# How do SQLite data types map to Java?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, sqldatatypes

SQLite only has a few data types: `NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, BLOB`

Meanwhile, the JDBC has:

```
-7  BIT,  
-6  TINYINT,  
-5  BIGINT,  
-4  LONGVARBINARY,  
-3  VARBINARY,  
-2  BINARY,  
-1  LONGVARCHAR, 
0   NULL,  
1   CHAR,  
2   NUMERIC,  
3   DECIMAL,  
4   INTEGER,  
5   SMALLINT,  
6   FLOAT,  
7   REAL,  
8   DOUBLE,  
12  VARCHAR,  
91  DATE,  
92  TIME,  
93  TIMESTAMP,   
1111    OTHER.  
(possibly more)
```

I can't find any documentation anywhere for the SQLite-specific JDBC driver, and I need to know how the driver maps the types.

Obviously null is null,
integer is integer (probably),
real is real (probably),
but what do text and blob map to?

Comment: There are several SQLite JDBC drivers. But might it be possible that you have one running right now on your computer?

Comment: I'm using the Xerial driver through IntelliJ IDEA specifically.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite uses dynamic typing.

The Xerial driver combines both the declared column type name and the actual type of the value to determine the JDBC type; see the [implementation of `getColumnType()`](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sqlite/jdbc3/JDBC3ResultSet.java#L656).
You get the JDBC type if the column's type name is in the following list, *and* if the actual type matches:

```
BOOLEAN
TINYINT
SMALLINT
INT2
BIGINT
INT8
UNSIGNED BIG INT
DATE
DATETIME
INT
INTEGER
MEDIUMINT
DECIMAL
DOUBLE
DOUBLE PRECISION
NUMERIC
REAL
FLOAT
CHARACTER
NCHAR
NATIVE CHARACTER
CLOB
DATE
DATETIME
VARCHAR
VARYING CHARACTER
NVARCHAR
TEXT
BINARY
BLOB
```

Otherwise, you get NULL.